# On a linear non-homogeneous system of differential equations.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I rewrite my  attempt at solving this system

\begin{cases} x'(t) = 3x(t) + y(t) + e^{2t} \\y'(t) = - x(t) + y(t) + e^t\\ x(0) = 1 \\ y(0) = 0 \end{cases}

I notice that the eigenvalue of the matrix associated with the homogeneous equation is $\lambda = 2$ with algebraic multiplicity of $2$.

Given that the matrix for $\lambda = 2$ has rank one I can only obtain one eigenvector $(1,-1)$ so I need to utilize generalized eigenvectors. The generalized eigenspace is all of $R^2$ so I just complete the basis and choose $(1,0)$.

the general solution for the associated homogeneous system is (correct?)

$$U(t) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
e^{2t}(t+1)  & e^{2t} \\
-e^{2t}t & -e^{2t} \\
 \end{array} \right)  $$

Now I want to apply the variation by constants method of Lagrange that tells me that a solution to the system will be

$$U(t) \int_{t_0}^t (U(s))^{-1} b(s) \, ds$$

where $t_0$ is a generic value belonging to the domain of $x,y$ and $b(s) = (e^{2s}, e^s)$.

I get
$$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
e^{2t}(t+1)  & e^{2t} \\
-e^{2t}t & -e^{2t} \\
 \end{array} \right) \int_0^t \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-e^{-2s}  & -e^{-2s} \\
se^{-2s} & e^{-2s}(s+1) \\
 \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
e^{2s}  \\ e^s \\
 \end{array} \right) \,ds. $$

This is $$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
e^{2t}(t+1)  & e^{2t} \\
-e^{2t}t & -e^{2t} \\
 \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
(t+1)e^{-t}  \\ t^2/2 + e^{-t} (-t -2) \\
 \end{array} \right) $$

Now I am unsure where to place the $c_1, c_2$ necessary to get a specific solution (since I have the initial values), If somebody could write the general solution to the system properly it would be helpful (first time solving a non homogeneous).

Answer (score 3):

Use Laplace transform:

- $$x'(t)=3x(t)+y(t)+e^{2t}\Longleftrightarrow sx(s)-x(0)=3x(s)+y(s)+\frac{1}{s-2}$$
- $$y'(t)=y(t)-x(t)+e^t\Longleftrightarrow sy(s)-y(0)=y(s)-x(s)+\frac{1}{s-1}$$

Now, use the intial conditions and simplify:

- $$x(s)=\frac{1+y(s)+\frac{1}{s-2}}{s-3}$$
- $$y(s)=\frac{\frac{1}{s-1}-x(s)}{s-1}$$

Now, substitute them into eachother:

- $$x(s)=\frac{1+\frac{\frac{1}{s-1}-x(s)}{s-1}+\frac{1}{s-2}}{s-3}\Longleftrightarrow x(s)=\frac{s^3-3s^2+4s-3}{\left(s-2\right)^3(s-1)}$$
- $$y(s)=\frac{\frac{1}{s-1}-\frac{1+y(s)+\frac{1}{s-2}}{s-3}}{s-1}\Longleftrightarrow y(s)=\frac{5-3s}{\left(s-2\right)^3(s-1)}$$

Now, use the inverse Laplace transform to find:

- $$x(t)=\frac{e^t\left(2+te^t\left(t+6\right)\right)}{2}$$
- $$y(t)=-\frac{e^t\left(4+e^t\left(t(t+4)-4\right)\right)}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, could you also just write the general solution with my method? and comment if it's al-right if you wish? (I now understand that Laplace transforms works better in this case, thanks!) .